# ClipBoard recovery

Tags: clipboard

Working on a word document with multiple changes. The final version was on the clipboard and now I cannot find the one I need with the final changes. It is only one day old. I do not have the auto recover feature on Is there any way to retrieve this final clipboard item?

Comment: Have you closed word since you copied it? Also, the clipboard isn't the best form of version control.

Comment: Clipboard is *not* the place to store things. It lasts until it's copied over, you quit the app, reboot the machine - pretty much anything...

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed anything for example copied something else, shut the machine down, etc. you WILL NOT be able to get that back. It is held in RAM and is wiped when the machine is shut off.